# Что произойдет с автоинкрименированным полем фиксированного размера после использования всех доступных индексов?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть поле типа **INT** с размером в **три** символа с свойством **autoincrement**. В таблице хранится с десяток записей. Эти записи часто обновляются и старые индексы удаляются, а не перезаписываются заново. Что произойдет когда значение этого поля превысит 999 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Число в скобках рядом с целочисленными типами данных в `mysql` - популярное заблуждение от того, что не читают [мануал](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-attributes.html).

> The display width does not constrain the range of values that can be  stored in the column. Nor does it prevent values wider than the column  display width from being displayed correctly. For example, a column specified as SMALLINT(3) has the usual SMALLINT range of -32768 to 32767, and values outside the range permitted by three digits are displayed in full using more than three digits.

Число в скобках не имеет никакого влияния. На него могут обращать внимание клиентские приложения, например, для выравнивания таблиц, но никакого влияния на данные это число не имеет. `int(1)` идентичен `int(11)`

Соответственно, ничего не будет. Будет значение 1000, затем 1001 и так далее.

Что произойдёт при достижении численного лимита вообще для поля - auto_increment будет выдавать максимальное значение (но не ошибку напрямую!), затем запрос в большинстве случаев будет спотыкаться на ограничении первичного ключа и только тут возвращать ошибку.

```
mysql> create table testai (id smallint primary key auto_increment, val int not null);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,01 sec)

mysql> alter table testai auto_increment = 32765;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,01 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> insert into testai (val) values(1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,01 sec)

mysql> insert into testai (val) values(1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,01 sec)

mysql> insert into testai (val) values(1);
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '32767' for key 'PRIMARY'
mysql> select * from testai;
+-------+-----+
| id    | val |
+-------+-----+
| 32765 |   1 |
| 32767 |   1 |
+-------+-----+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> insert into testai (val) values(5) on duplicate key update val=5;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> select * from testai;
+-------+-----+
| id    | val |
+-------+-----+
| 32765 |   1 |
| 32767 |   5 |
+-------+-----+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Из-за того, что auto_increment продолжает возвращать конкретное и допустимое число, интересен пример с `on duplicate key update` - он будет бесконечно обновлять последнюю вставленную строку.

Comment: Так с диапазоном значений разобрались, а что произойдет при исчерпании этого лимита?

Comment: Очевидно же - stackoverflow. Ну а если серьезно - получите ошибку при попытке любой вставки (в MySQL точно не скажу ее точной вид) и будет 3 пути ее обхода: изменить int на numeric, либо создать новую таблицу, либо заархивировать часть данных и сбросить счетчик для нужного значения.